# PySpark join columns after pivot

Tags: pyspark

For the following example DataFrame:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    ('2017-01-01', 'A', 1),
    ('2017-01-01', 'B', 2),
    ('2017-01-01', 'C', 3),
    ('2017-01-02', 'A', 4),
    ('2017-01-02', 'B', 5),
    ('2017-01-02', 'C', 6),
    ('2017-01-03', 'A', 7),
    ('2017-01-03', 'B', 8),
    ('2017-01-03', 'C', 9),
],
('date', 'type', 'value')
)
```

I would like to convert it to have the columns equal to all unique "types" (A, B, and C).

Currently, I have found this code works closest to what I would like to achieve:

```
 df.groupby("date", "type").pivot("type").sum().orderBy("date").show()

+----------+----+----+----+----+
|      date|type|   A|   B|   C|
+----------+----+----+----+----+
|2017-01-01|   C|null|null|   3|
|2017-01-01|   A|   1|null|null|
|2017-01-01|   B|null|   2|null|
|2017-01-02|   B|null|   5|null|
|2017-01-02|   C|null|null|   6|
|2017-01-02|   A|   4|null|null|
|2017-01-03|   A|   7|null|null|
|2017-01-03|   C|null|null|   9|
|2017-01-03|   B|null|   8|null|
+----------+----+----+----+----+
```

The issue is that I still have too many rows (containing all "null").

What I would like to get is:

```
+----------+---+---+---+
|      date|  A|  B|  C|
+----------+---+---+---+
|2017-01-01|  1|  2|  3|
|2017-01-02|  4|  5|  6|
|2017-01-03|  7|  8|  9|
+----------+---+---+---+
```

Aka, I would like something that has similar functionality to pandas.DataFrame.unstack().

If anyone has any tips on how I can achieve this in PySpark that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do another group by `"date"` column then select `max` values from `A,B,C`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.groupby("date", "type").pivot("type").sum().orderBy("date").groupBy("date").agg(max(col("A")).alias("A"),max(col("B")).

#+----------+---+---+---+
#|      date|  A|  B|  c|
#+----------+---+---+---+
#|2017-01-01|  1|  2|  3|
#|2017-01-02|  4|  5|  6|
#|2017-01-03|  7|  8|  9|
#+----------+---+---+---+

# dynamic way 
aggregate = ["A","B","C"]
funs=[max]
exprs=[f(col(c)).alias(c) for f in funs for c in aggregate]
df.groupby("date", "type").pivot("type").sum().orderBy("date").groupBy("date").agg(*exprs).show()

#+----------+---+---+---+
#|      date|  A|  B|  c|
#+----------+---+---+---+
#|2017-01-01|  1|  2|  3|
#|2017-01-02|  4|  5|  6|
#|2017-01-03|  7|  8|  9|
#+----------+---+---+---+
```